# ¿Cómo convertir JSON A UNA TABLA SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, json

Estoy intentando convertir un JSON pero me sale mal.

**1- La estructura es:**

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"saldoAtualizado": {
    "valorDivida": 851.64
}
```

}

**2 - La query es:**

DECLARE @JSON AS VARCHAR(MAX) =

'{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"saldoAtualizado": {
"valorDivida": 851.64
}
}'

SELECT
status
,valorDivida

FROM OPENJSON ( @JSON )
with ( status                 varchar(50) '$.status'
,valorDivida

**3 - el resultado es:**

status    valorDivida

SUCCESS  NULL

Agradesco a quien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el valor de valorDivida tienes que introducir el path completo del mismo.

```
DECLARE @JSON AS VARCHAR(MAX) =

'{ "status": "SUCCESS", "saldoAtualizado": { "valorDivida": 851.64 } }'

SELECT
*

FROM OPENJSON ( @JSON ) with ( status varchar(50),valorDivida float '$.saldoAtualizado.valorDivida' )
```

[image: Res]

[OpenJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Javi fer2, gracias por compartir tus conocimientos.